# Issue passing data between multiple activities using extra bundle (same key)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bundle

I have 3 activities `ActivityA`,`ActivityB`,`ActivityC`.

I want to pass a `Long` from `ActivityA` to `AtivityB` to `ActivityC`.

For that I'm using the extra bundle of the intent, and using the **same key**.

Here is part of the code:

**ActivityA**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra(ActivityB.MY_KEY, Long.valueOf(3000));
startActivity(i);
```

**ActivityB**

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(ActivityB.MY_KEY))
        myId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(ActivityB.MY_KEY, -1);
//after this, myId = 3000
```

Later in the activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
i.putExtra(ActivityB.MY_KEY, Long.valueOf(myId));
startActivity(i);
```

**ActivityC**

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra(ActivityB.MY_KEY))
        myId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong(ActivityB.MY_KEY, -1);
//after this, myId = -1
```

But if I use another Key to pass from `B` to `C`, it works as expected, myId will be 3000.

Can someone tell me why this happens? I'm pretty sure I already had this issue in the past, but I don't remember the explanation...

**UPDATE**
I think I found what could be the issue, but not a solution yet.

The problem isn't related with the fact that I'm using the same key, but with the fact that along with this value, I'm trying to send a parcelabe object...

When I remove this parcelable, the value is passed correctly.

Do you think it could be something related with the implementation of the parcelable implementation?

Sorry for not telling about this from the beggining but I didn't know it could affect...

Comment: Have you set a log or breakpoint in `ActivityB` at `i.putExtra(ActivityB.MY_KEY, Long.valueOf(myId));` to see what the value of `myId` is?

Comment: If your ActivityC code is accurate, then ActivityB would appear to be putting -1 into the extras (otherwise, you would not enter the `if` block). You might consider examining the extras `Bundle` in the debugger, both on the `Intent` that B is passing to C (before the `startActivity()` call) and in C (to confirm your code is executing as expected).

Comment: @codeMagic It has the correct value

Comment: Is Activity C being called from anywhere else? Where is the code in the last activity located?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you check my update please?

Comment: @codeMagic Can you check my update please?

Comment: Are these activities all in the same app? Are you really using `startActivity()`, or are you doing something else (e.g., using a `PendingIntent`)? Custom `Parcelable` classes [can be trouble](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/07/22/be-careful-where-you-use-custom-parcelables.html), but I am not aware of a problem when using them for simple `startActivity()` calls. With the `Parcelable` in the extras, check LogCat for any errors or warnings from the system.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it is only activities and both of them are in the same app. Well, I solved it passing the id of the object and getting the object in the final activity...